# Stop two objects overlapping

Tags: html, css

I am building a website to host an online gameserver list for the game Crysis Wars, and have just found out that it's by far easier just to develop the design in Adobe Fireworks, and add the relevant code after.

The current web page that I am designing has a signin box at the center of the page, and it works beautifully.
That is, until we change the size of the browser window.

This is the web page as it normally looks:
[image]

It is displayed correctly, but here's the screenshot of when the browser window was resized:

[image]

As can be seen, this is an issue with the page, since visitors will have different screen resolutions, and this problem could easily re-occur.

My question is, how can I force these two CSS objects to maintain their position, and never overlap?
This is troublesome since the signin box centers itself on the web page.

The web page can be viewed at [crysis-or.eu](http://crysis-or.eu/) (please don't berate me for developing on a live website).

HTML Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Server Portal | Login</title>
        <link href="./css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
        </div>
        <div class="loginui">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:-0px;
    background-color:07080A;
}

body > .loginui {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
    background:url("http://crysis-or.eu/img/login_b_bg.png") repeat-x;
}

body > .navbar {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:100px;

    background:url("http://crysis-or.eu/img/navbar.png") repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: The problem is caused by your body always being 100% the width of the window, which means that the window cannot hold the two items next to eachother, you need to set a min-width (and probly min-height as well ), this will stop the body of your page from getting too small. Check my answer for syntax.

Comment: Revamped my answer after playing around with the resizing on your site for a couple minutes.

Comment: @PugsOverDrugs Just did some more testing, and the problem seems to be with the log-in `div`; it automatically centers itself when the browser window is resized.

Comment: I see what you mean, ill play with it a bit and get back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

Put the nav bar and the login window in separate wrapper-divs that prevent them from overlapping. You can change your HTML to:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Server Portal | Login</title>
        <link href="./css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="top-bar">
            <div class="navbar">
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            <div class="loginui">
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Header and Section act just like Div, the only difference is their semantic significance.

Because the .top-bar and .loginui are no longer direct children of the body, your selectors won't work anymore. Change the CSS selectors to just `.top-bar` and `.loginui` instead of `body > .top-bar` and `body > .loginui`.

The header needs a specified height, and needs its position to be either 'relative' or 'absolute'. An absolutely positioned child element will be positioned absolutely to whatever the closest parent is that is also absolute, or explicitly relative. The background color is for illustration purposes only, and would be removed for production.

```
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

You want the section to fill as much as it can, so it will need absolute positioning. **The trick here, the thing that will fix your problem**, is adding a min-height attribute to prevent the section from becoming smaller than its contents, thus allowing overlap.

```
section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

That should work for you. The one problem with this solution is that the login window will be centered with respect to its container, rather than the whole window. It will be 100 pixels lower (one half of the header height) than it is with your current design. In order to fix that, if that's important to you, you would need to use a different method of vertically centering it. Put the top as 50%, then use a negative top margin to compensate for half the height plus half of the height of the header, too. Because it has a fixed height, that's easy: (400px + 200px) / 2 = 300px.

```
.loginui {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right; 0;
    margin: -300px auto 0;
    background: url('path/to/login_b_bg.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add this, it will create a scrollbar when trying to resize the browser instead of laying the elements on top of eachother

```
body 
{
    width:100%;
    min-width: 950px; //ADD THIS. It sets the minimum browser width before creating a scroll bar.
    min-height: 550px; // This does the same thing for a vertical scroll bar.
    margin-left:-0px;
    background-color:07080A;
    overflow-y: scroll; // vertical scroll bar
    overflow-x: scroll; //horizontal scroll bar
}
```

EDIT: ---------------------------------

After looking at your site and playing around a bit, your min-width is not an important factor, just the min height, if you set the values like this, the menus will never overlap.

```
body 
{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 750px; // Stops the menus from touching eachother vertically, but they can still line up in the x-direction.
    margin-left:-0px;
    background-color:07080A;
    overflow-y: scroll; // vertical scroll bar
}
```